# QGIS 3D and QGIS Webmap, Javascript; Search Bar

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I exported my webmap, using QGIS2web.

The QGIS2web already has a search bar, but the placement icon when I search, as it applies to my project, always shows below my uploaded raster images. When I zoom in it vanishes, because the size of the search icon reduces, and lies below my raster files. I used a series of images to explain.

[image]
**Figure 1**: I highlighted my uploaded polygon at the right bottom corner. The underlying map is OSM.

[image]
**Figure 2**: I searched for a feature, and the box suggested related features for me in the top left area.

[image]
**Figure 3**: haven clicked the enter icon to validate my search, I unchecked the images, showing the underlying OSM. You should be able to see the blue dot representing the response of the search

[image]
**Figure 4**: As I zoomed inward, the blue dot becomes clearer, radiating from beneath my polygon that I didn't uncheck.

[image]
**Figure 5**: As I zoomed further inward, the search response icon becomes smaller than my individual raster, therefore unable to show, as its default is to show under my polygon (this is what I want to correct. I want it to show above my images.)

[image]
**Figure 6**: To prove that it was underneath, as I unchecked my raster images, it became more clearly visible.
Isn't it possible to just have the search function highlight my search feature in a different color, instead of using a dot to point to it, as is the case here?